# My issue is when multiple jobs fail in the pipeline, only one error gets reported back to the pull request

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

I have an Azure DevOps build validation pipeline (yml) that runs multiple jobs. The pipeline has 4 checks and these checks are dependent on build (all 4 checks and build in same pipeline). This pipeline, is setup as a build validation policy on the main branch. Whenever a pipeline is created or updated, this pipeline triggers and will run the checks. My issue is when multiple jobs fail in the pipeline, only one error gets reported back to the pull request.

i have tried making different pipelines for all the checks and adding them in build validation, this gives status of each check. But i have to do "build" for every pipeline, which is not desirable.

Is there any way each job status gets reported on the PR.

i have tried the above

Comment: I can reproduce the same issue when using Pull Request Build validation. The issue should come from the Azure DevOps Pull Request feature itself. I suggest that you can report the issue to the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report) Azure DevOps developers will further investigate and resolve issues with Azure DevOps itself.